# Get latest Git tag for NPM project

Tags: git, npm, npm-publish

Looks like when you run `npm publish` it creates a git tag for you. That's weird that it does that automatically.

When I run `git describe --tags`, I see:

```
v1.1.512218-311-g9f79efe
```

when I run `git tag`, I see:

```
0.0.2
v1.1.512215
v1.1.512216
v1.1.512217
v1.1.512218
v1.1.512219
v1.1.512220
v1.1.512221
v1.1.512222
v1.1.51243
```

**my question is** - how do I get the latest git tag for all git branches? How do I get the latest git tag for just the `master` branch?

**What I want to do is** compare the most recent commit in a Git repo, with the latest tag, to see if there is a difference. If there is a difference, then I need to create a new tag and publish a new version to NPM.

Answer (score 1):

~ I think you will need to link them as thay are not linked. ~

~~ NPN version are in the `package.json` file and git tags are a command of there own ~~

~~ I think this stack overflow post 
 [Automate Git commit + versioning + tag by npm node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460008/automate-git-commit-versioning-tag-by-npm-node#38484417) will help ~~

**Edit**: After comments:

I see the [supported node version](https://github.com/sumanjs/suman/blob/master/package.json#L5) is `>=6` but there is nothing in the `.npmrc` file about versions. This may be a silly question but you are using the right node version?

Comment: bro, please do research before you comment/answer. If you watch this video, it explains that when `npm publish` is run, npm creates a git tag for you. https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

Comment: sorry this must be an update I have missed. Things do move fast and I am the first to admit I miss stuff from time to time.

Comment: ... Done research (watch the link). Is it possible to see the `package.json` and `.npmrc` file please. That me help me.

Comment: I think it is the `npm version` command that generates the git tag, not `npm publish` - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6711

Comment: I must admit now you mention it. I was not paying 100% to that part. it was defo' worth playing it! .... also LOL -> `"start": "echo 'this is not what you are looking for.'"`

Comment: yeah haha I don't like `npm scripts`, I think they are a bad crutch, etc

Comment: also I see [yarn stuff in your repo](https://github.com/sumanjs/suman/blob/master/.gitignore#L19) does that have an affect or is it just a hangover from, times past.

Comment: Yeah I am not using yarn on that project, for the moment

Comment: Updated awnser but I think I am about done in how I can help you at this point as my typing (English skills) suck :(

Comment: hey np, maybe come back to it later, thanks anyway though